# Authorization bearer token Angular 6 not working

Tags: angular, authorization, bearer-token

I'm new to Angular and I'm working on a project. I need to set bearer token for some API calls. This is what I tried.

```
getData(){
this.apiService.get('Services/getall', true).subscribe((data) => {
    console.log("data" + data);
},error => {

return throwError(error);  
});
}
```

APIService.get Method

```
/* Make get request to API*/
        get(url: string, authorized: boolean = false ) : Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(apiUrl + url, { headers: this.getHeaders(authorized) }).pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
    }
```

If the API needs a bearer token

```
    /**
* set authorization headers
*/
getHeaders(authorized: boolean) {
    let userToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken');

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    if (authorized) {
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + userToken);
    }   
    return headers;

}
```

But this is not working. I'm getting 401 error. API is working without any issues when I'm trying with Postman.

Could you please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HttpHeaders.append does not modify your existing Headers. Instead it returns a clone with the new Entry added. So you'll need to assign it to headers again.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    if (authorized) {
        headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + userToken);
    }
```

Also, i guess you don't need to set the json contentType. Angular will do it you you if needed.

You may want to use [HTTP Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) in future to automatically add the bearer to all of your requests

Comment: Thanks a lot A.Winnen

Comment: headers = headers.append('Authorization',  userToken); **removing 'Bearer' works for me**